# How to Store data from httpClient Post response?

Tags: typescript, httpclient, angular8

I am trying to store a token on session storage after getting a response but when I compile this code I get error **Property 'access_token' does not exist on type 'Object'**. This error is showing before sending a request and i want to execute sesssionstorage when i get a response not before sending a request.

```
 this.http.post(url,null,
   {
     headers : new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Authorization' :'Basic '+ btoa('username:password')
     })
   }
   ).subscribe(
    data => { // json data

      console.log('Success: ', data);
      sessionStorage.setItem("Token ",data.access_token)
  },
  error => {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
  }
   )


  }
```

Comment: can u make a stackblitz click here to make [here](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is your response data type? you could use any type and write it like this.but
the good practice is to write an interface with response data.

```
  {
    headers : new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization' :'Basic '+ btoa('username:password')
    })
  }
  ).subscribe(
   (data: any) => { // json data

     console.log('Success: ', data);
     sessionStorage.setItem("Token ",data.access_token)
   },
   error => {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   }
  )
 }
```